# Magnolia CMS - check other users permission

Tags: jcr, magnolia

I would like to check if a specific user (specified by name, not the current user) has write access to some arbirary path: for example:

"check is user 'foo' has write access to node '/contacts/common/bar'"

So far i can only see methods that allow to check permissions for the current user only. Is there a more generic method that allows for such a check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to AdminCentral as superuser, then go to Tools/Permissions, type in name of the user you want to check, check "show permissions" check box and click on "Get Permission List" button. If you want to do same programatically, check code in `info.magnolia.module.admininterface.pages.PermissionPage`. It pretty much boils down to getting `UserManager`, obtaining user from it, then iterating through all the groups and roles assigned to user to obtain all ACLs and then just listing those.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: is it enough just to iterate over every acl from user.getAllRoles()? it should include every role the user has including roles assigned via every group?

Comment: yes, if you don't care to know which group this role came through, then it is enough. But if you want to discover full hierarchy you have to iterate just like the code I mentioned above does.